# How to batchWriteItem of JSON to local DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to AWS and I am trying to understand how to use batchWriteItem. I have a local JSON file that I pulled from my DynamoDB in AWS using the dynamodb terminal command:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name my_aws_table > my_aws_table_seed.json --region us-east-1
```

An example of the JSON file looks like this:

```
{
    "Count": 1, 
    "Items": [ 
        {
            "user_number": {
                "S": "1"
            }, 
            "end_time": {
                "N": "230987109"
            }, 
            "create": {
                "N": "7509821156"
            }, 
            "group": {
                "S": "1"
            }, 
            "input": {
                "S": "1"
            }, 
            "name": {
                "S": "Test Item"
            }, 
            "input_id": {
                "N": "23509781098"
            }, 
            "output_id": {
                "N": "23409811545"
            }, 
            "start_time": {
                "N": "12235908722"
            }
        }
    ], 
    "ScannedCount": 1, 
    "ConsumedCapacity": null
}
```

What I am trying to do is take the table from DynamoDB that is on AWS and be able to seed / copy that data to my local serverless dynamodb table.

Answer (score 0):

I figured a way to do so via the CLI by **sls dynamodb start --seed=test**

And adding to my serverless.yml file:

```
dynamodb:
  start:
    seed: true

  seed:
    domain:
      sources:
        - table: domain-widgets
          sources: [./domainWidgets.json]
        - table: domain-fidgets
          sources: [./domainFidgets.json]
    test:
      sources:
        - table: users
          rawsources: [./fake-test-users.json]
        - table: subscriptions
          sources: [./fake-test-subscriptions.json]
```